# Unable to see UIActivityIndicator in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview, loading, uiactivityindicatorview

I am new to iPhone developer,

I am loading pages in my webview, loading takes too much time so i wan to show `ActivityIndicator` till the page loads,

Here is my code snippet but it is not working,

```
activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(200.0, 200.0, 100.0, 40.0);
    activityIndicator.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview: activityIndicator];

    _webview=[[UIWebView alloc]init];
    [_webview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [_webview setDelegate:(id<UIWebViewDelegate>)self];
    [self.view addSubview:_webview];

    [_webview bringSubviewToFront:activityIndicator];
```

...

```
 - (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

     [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

     [activityIndicator startAnimating];
     activityIndicator.hidden=FALSE;
 }

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    activityIndicator.hidden=TRUE;
}
```

but i am unable to see my `activityIndicator`

**Any help will be appreciated.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding the `UIActivityIndicatorView` directly to the `self.view` and later you are trying to `bringSubviewToFront` from the `UIWebView`. Check with:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:activityIndicator];
```

Answer (score 1):

Change  `[_webview bringSubviewToFront:activityIndicator];` to  `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:activityIndicator];`

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the order in which you add subviews. Add the webview first, and then add the activity indicator:

```
_webview=[[UIWebView alloc]init];
[_webview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
[_webview setDelegate:(id<UIWebViewDelegate>)self];
[self.view addSubview:_webview];

activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(200.0, 200.0, 100.0, 40.0);//you should also keep the height and width equal
activityIndicator.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview: activityIndicator];
```

And get rid of the line that follows:`[_webview bringSubviewToFront:activityIndicator];`